# Programming a fall-back for in-memory python object retrieval

Tags: django, redis

In a Django website of mine, there's a newsfeed made up of text and photos that everyone is able to view. The newsfeed is made up of 2000 latest user submissions, **globally** viewed by everyone.

I've been using redis to store and retrieve these user submissions. However, to speed things up, I'm now going to look up the latest 2000 submissions directly from memory.

I'll do this via pushing IDs of new entries into a python `list`, and saving the submitted data in a corresponding python `dictionary`. Moreover, I'll trim the `list` if it's `len` is above 2000, and call the `clear()` method on the corresponding dictionaries that have to be removed. This way my memory wouldn't overflow.

My question is about handling **persistence**. An edge case occurs where memory is wiped (e.g. a restart). How should I handle this case?

One way I can think of is keeping copies of user submissions in redis. Upon restart, I retrieve the data from redis once. From then on, I again keep retrieving everything from memory (and a copy in redis).

The scheme above looks like the right way to handle *the need for persistence, whilst employing the speed of in-memory retrieval* (which is what I'm trying to do). I'm about to implement this, but wanted to run it by the community in case I'm overlooking something.

Comment: I think you're making it too complicated. Redis is very fast for most scenario. What's your performance problem? Do you need to show the 2000 submission at the same time?

Comment: @for_stack: indeed, redis is quite fast. However, accessing in-memory python objects is much faster. I ran a comparison; the results were unmistakable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203443/benchmarking-retrieval-from-redis-vs-memory-in-python-using-timeit I paginate the 2000 submission objects, dividing them over 100 pages. With lots of users accessing the newsfeed page concurrently, I can speed up the whole process via using memory directly.

Comment: @for_stack: as for the performance problem, most of my users are on slow, 2G networks. So any way I can make the experience faster for them is a welcome step.

Comment: Of course, in-memory object is faster. Say, for each request, Redis is 10ms slower. That won't be a problem. Users cannot feel the difference. It seams your main problem is users' poor network.So you should do some compression on the result before sending to users. That would improve their experience better

Comment: @for_stack: well I do use gzip on nginx, so was looking at what else I can do to give users a faster experience.

Comment: I guess a big issue here is the intricacy of managing global python lists and dictionaries.

Comment: I don't think it will make too much difference. However, if you insist  on it, you can try something like this: use Redis as the data store (if you don't minding losing 1 sec of data, when Redis shutdown unexpectedly), and use a in-memory LRU cache in your python code. In this way, the code won't be too much complicated.

Comment: @for_stack: well my friend, I suppose you can add all of this (w/ a quick illustrative example) as an answer, and I'll accept it so we conclude this discussion elegantly. Getting your perspective has taught me a couple of things, so I'm sure future readers will benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, the main problem is users' poor network. Your current solution, i.e. compress the data before sending it to users, is pretty good.

Redis is fast enough for most scenarios, although it's slower than in-memory object operations (since there's a cost for data serialization/deserialization, and Inter-Process-Communication). However, if the data to be returned to user is not very large, that't won't be a problem. Say, Redis is `10ms` slower, but users won't feel the difference.

On the other hand, if you replace Redis with in-memory operations, you have to do the persistence work yourself, and that might make your code much more complicated.

Normally, we use **cache** to improve performance, and Redis is a good option for caching. You can have a SQL/NoSQL database (e.g. Mysql, MongoDB) to store data, and use Redis as a LRU cache.

In your case, you use Redis as the data store, and don't mind losing some data when Redis exits unexpectedly. In order to reduce the cost of data serialization/deserialization and IPC between your python process and Redis, you can have an in-memory LRU cache in your python code. That might improve the performance a bit, and won't make the code too complicated.